# Twisted - how to create multi protocol process and send the data between the protocols

Tags: python, xmpp, twisted, irc

Im trying to write a program that would be listening for data (simple text messages) on some port (say tcp 6666) and then pass them to one or more different protocols - irc, xmpp and so on. I've tried many approaches and digged the Internet, but I cant find easy and working solution for such task.

The code I am currently fighting with is here: http://pastebin.com/ri7caXih

I would like to know how to from object like:

ircf = ircFactory('asdfasdf', '#asdf666')

get access to self protocol methods, because this:

self.protocol.dupa1(msg)

returns error about self not being passed to active protocol object. Or maybe there is other, better, easier and more kosher way to create single reactor with multiple protocols and have actions triggeres when a message arrives on any of them, and then pass that message to other protocols for handling/processing/sending?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Here is sample code to read from multiple connections to port 9001 and write out to a connection on port 9000.  You would need multiple "PutLine" implementations, one for XMPP, IRC, MSN, etc.

I used a global to store the output connection PutLine but you would want to create a more complex Factory object that would handle this instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import clientFromString, serverFromString
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

queue = []
putter = None

class GetLine(LineReceiver):
    delimiter = '\n'

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        queue.append(line)
        putter.have_data()
        self.sendLine(line)

class PutLine(LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self):
        global putter
        putter = self
        print 'putline init called %s' % str(self)

    def have_data(self):
        line = queue.pop()
        self.sendLine(line)


def main():
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = PutLine
    endpoint = clientFromString(reactor, "tcp:host=localhost:port=9000")
    endpoint.connect(f)
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = GetLine
    endpoint2 = serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:port=9001")
    endpoint2.listen(f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Testing:

```
nc -l  9000
python test.py
nc 9001
```

Data entered form any number of nc 9001 (or netcat 9001) will appear on nc -l 9000.

Answer (score 3):

This is answered in the FAQ.

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother

Comment: Nope.  That example is read from all, write to all.  The original poster (and myself) are looking for "read from a bunch" write to a "different bunch".

Comment: Only "nope" in that it is not an exact implementation of what the poster wants.  It's an example, it's not a solution.  Look at it and learn from it.  Can't you see how you might replace the loop over all clients with some other selection criteria?

Comment: Still nope.   You need to connect from on protocol to another.  This example just shows how to rewrite with a protocol.  Did you really vote down my actual working answer?

Comment: No problem,  my answer is back up to 0.

Answer (score 1):

See [`doc/core/examples/chatserver.py`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/examples/chatserver.py).  There they've added hooks to the `Protocol`'s `connectionMade` and `connectionLost` methods to maintain a list of connected clients, and then it iterates through all of them when a message arrives to pass on.

Comment: I think, it does not resolve my issue - what that example does, is sending a message to every connected client in range of one protocol. What I am trying to do, is to receive a text line on some port, and then pass it to two or more different protocols, where it could be processed according to protocols defined methods when receiving a message - like pasting received line to irc channel, sending via xmpp to jabber clients, and so on.

Comment: So you'll have to do what the example does, in terms of keeping track of the connected clients (on each protocol), but also add some higher-level object that keeps track of all of those.  That might be a `Service` you create that holds reference to your `irc` and `nagios` factories, and passes messages to them.

Comment: Well - it seems that I am not explaining the issue simply enought. This code aims to be listening on port 6666 and at the same time logged on irc (lets drop the jabber thing for now) as a bot, that will send message received on port 6666 to irc channel he will be logged on. This is not an issue of sending messages between multiple clients in one protocol, but passing data between two (or more) independent protocols/factories. I hope this helps to understand the issue behind the code.